# Fix for "TclError: can't invoke "button" command"?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm attempting tkinter in python for the first time but the `Button` command creates an error

```
from tkinter import *
fenetre=Tk()
label=Label(fenetre,text="Hello World ! ")
label.pack() 
fenetre.mainloop()
bouton=Button(fenetre,text="fermer", command=fenetre.quit)
boutoun.pack()
```

It should create a window with a button but I just receive the error message:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-fd57f3be1272> in <module>
----> 1 bouton=Button(fenetre,text="Exit !", command=fenetre.quit)
      2 boutoun.pack()

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)
   2648             overrelief, state, width
   2649         """
-> 2650         Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
   2651 
   2652     def flash(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, master, widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)
   2570         for k, v in classes:
   2571             del cnf[k]
-> 2572         self.tk.call(
   2573             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
   2574         for k, v in classes:

TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed```
There's some similar questions in the forum but unfortunately they do not work for me.
````

Comment: `fenetre.mainloop()` should come towards the end of the code, not in between. The code below `mainloop()` only runs when the GUI is exited.

Comment: The call to `fenetre.mainloop()` returns when the tkinter window is closed, thus the error. Put the statement at the end of your script.

Comment: It works now ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
from tkinter import *
fenetre=Tk()
label=Label(fenetre,text="Hello World ! ")
label.pack() 
bouton=Button(fenetre,text="fermer", command=fenetre.destroy)  # HERE (1)
bouton.pack()
fenetre.mainloop()  # HERE (2)
```

1. Use `fenetre.destroy` instead of `fenetre.quit`
2. The main loop should be the last line to catch events (to be simple)

Comment: Thank you ! @Corralien